# How to speed up "for" loop in PHP (creating a very large array)?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, loops, for-loop

I'm struggling with finding a method of speeding up operations in a loop, which is creating an array (a VLA). What is the best way to do this? Maybe there's another, better approach to a task like that?

The script assigns random numbers to usernames, it's later used in some other calculations. I need **$i to be in the billions or even trillions**. What's the fastest way to build an array like that? Right now it's taking seconds for low values like 10M. I need this to be shorter than one second.

```
$username = "james.brown";
$theArray = array();

// 10 MLN takes more than 3 secs, too long!
for ($i=0; $i<10000000; $i++) {

    $random = rand(0,1000000000);
    $ourRandomNumber = $random;
    $theArray[] = $username . ":" . $ourRandomNumber;

}
```

Maybe another programming language at all..?

Comment: is there a reason why `$i` can't start at 1 billion or trillion?

Comment: Yes, i need to generate billions / trillions of rows, so it doesn't matter if it starts from 0 or 1B. It still needs to go through billions of iterations.

Comment: this might help, https://pageconfig.com/post/faster-random-numbers-with-php

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem.  Why would you possibly need to run this type of iteration often enough that you care about it being under 1s?

Comment: Using `++$i` instead of `$i++` has significant performance benefits since you're going into the millions

Comment: Quite honestly, I am impressed that it's only taking 3 seconds. You must have quite a powerhouse of a server. I agree with @Devon in that it really does not make sense why this heavy operation needs to be under 1s. There probably is a better way to achieve your ultimate goal but unless we know more details then it's just a guessing game. If you sincerely need this level of computational power then you probably need to move away from PHP for this operation.

Comment: You could combine all three lines into one, eliminating two variable-assignments:  `$theArray[] = $username . ":" . rand(0,1000000000);`.  Also, using commas `,` in a concatenated string [is slightly faster](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/) than using periods `.`

Comment: What about array_fill?

``
$username = "james.brown";
$theArray = [];

$theArray = array_fill(0,10000000, $username);
foreach($theArray as $k => &$a){ $theArray[$k] = $theArray[$k] . ":".rand(0,1000000000); }
``